# Make AJAX PHP script use same session as main page

Tags: ajax, sessionid, php

I have a main page that starts a PHP session, which creates session ID #1. I check this with `session_id()`.  I want to access these session variables from a PHP AJAX script.  To test this i just simply execute:

```
session_start();
echo session_id();
```

from this AJAX script.  It returns a different AJAX  session ID.

I know I can pass the session ID from the main page to the AJAX script.  Is there another way to make the AJAX script open the same session by default?

For clarification I am doing this via javascript, more specifically it is the add/edit script for JQGrid.

Comment: how are you making a call? If it is via JS, it should have the same session id. If it is flash, it is different.

Comment: This is to do with the scope of your session cookie. Obviously the location called by your AJAX call falls outside the scope of your session cookie - to fix this, you either need to [widen the scope](http://php.net/session-set-cookie-params) of the cookie or change the target location so that it falls within the existing scope. Alternatively, you could manually pass the session ID as a GET or POST parameter in the AJAX request. Further reading on cookie scope [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Domain_and_Path).

Comment: @DaveRandom - Thanks for the info about the cookie scope.  I think this must be the problem.  The session variable is defined in the web root -> index.php file, and the AJAX script is in a sub folder of the web root.  I will try to widen the scope.  I think you could post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple.

in ajax, post your session_id to the ajax php.

in ajax php set it like: session_id($_REQUEST['sid'])

then you are in the same session